# why referenced static class member not accessible in one project but fine in other project

Tags: c#, reference, project

the referenced class in the object browser is shown as follows:
[image: result in object browser launched from references]
[image: project reference]

without the use of using RegexParse4Lib
visual studio 2012 intellesense suggested using

```
RegexParse4Lib.regexParse.RegexReplace(...
```

however, when completed it flagged RegexReplace as not exists. on the other hand

```
Regex.Replace(...
```

is accepted

Even more puzzling is that I can not add using RegexParse4Lib; despite intellisense allow me to put it in a class's beginning

Comment: Maybe the project which is referencing it is running in client profile mode. Check the properties

Comment: Thank you @CodingYoshi; you definitely helped me find the problem.

the "problematic project" is using .net framework 4 while the others are using .net 4.5.

After changing the "problematic project" to use .net framework 4.5, I was able to add "using RegexParse4Lib".

I guess the RegexParse4Lib was built with .net framework 4.5 so it can cause trouble when using on .net 4 project.

Comment: Thats great! I wrote an answer in any case someone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the project which is referencing the library is a *Client Profile* (this is a subset of .NET full version) and the library is a regular version (Not client profile).

This can also happen if the *Target Framework* of the project you are referencing is higher. If the library you are trying to reference has a lower framework version, then it should be fine because .NET Framework versions are backward compatible. However, if you are trying to reference a library which has a higher framework version then it will not work: It is possible the library has code taking advantage of new .net features which are not available in the older framework.

Change the project to have an equal or higher framework version than the library.